# use of old package GenABEL

Tags: package, transformation

I would like to use the package GenABEL which is no longer available but archived.

I tried to install it

path<- "http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/GenABEL.data/GenABEL.data_1.0.0.tar.gz"
install.packages(path, repos=NULL, type="source")

Despite the successful installation, I get the error message "rntransform" not found.

Can someone help me?

I found the rntransform option really useful but cannot get it to work any longer.

Thank you!
Leonie

Answer (score 0):

The link you posted is for downloading datasets used in GenABEL. Do you still have the same issue after downloading the GenABEL package (https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/GenABEL/)?